# Is HtmlUnit 2.8 getFirstByXPath different from HtmlUnit 1.14 getFirstByXPath?

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

I have a site structure that looks something like this:

```
<div class='main_container'>
     <div class='item_container'>
         <div class='body'>
             <span class='item_name'>Item 1</span>
             <span class='item_desc'>Desc 1</span>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class='item_container'>
         <div class='body'>
             <span class='item_name'>Item 2</span>
             <span class='item_desc'>Desc 2</span>
         </div>
     </div>
     ...
</div><!--End of main_container--> 
//Note: Some divs might not have <span @class='item_name'>Item N</span> or other elements inside the item_container
```

In HtmlUnit 1.14 if I want to get all item name:

```
List<HtmlDivision> divs = (List<HtmlDivision>)page.getByXPath("//div[@class='item_container']");
for(HtmlDivision div:divs){
    String name = ((HtmlElement)div.getFirstByXPath("//span[@class='item_name']")).asText();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Output:

```
Item 1
Item 2
...
```

But in HtmlUnit 2.8 when I do the same I got.

```
Item 1
Item 1
...
```

Is there a workaround on this in HtmlUnit 2.8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be that HtmlUnit 1.4 had a bug that you were exploiting/relying on.

In the code that you showed, the XPath inside of the `for` loop should return the same element each time it executes(as it does in v2.8), because it starts with `//`, which looks through the ***entire document*** starting at the root node and returns the ***first one*** that it finds.

If you want it to be relative from the `<div>` in the loop, you should adjust your XPath to: `.//span[@class='item_name']`

Comment: JavaDoc for the method says  "Evaluates the specified XPath expression from this node, returning the first matching element, or null if no node matches the specified XPath expression." So shouldn't it search for elements within the node on which this method is called ?